# Could i be using a bind/fmap here

Tags: haskell

```
loadTexture :: String -> IO (Either String GL.GLuint)
loadTexture filename = do
    p <- PNG.loadPNGFile filename
    oglLoadImg p
    where
        oglLoadImg :: (Either String PNG.PNGImage) -> IO (Either String GL.GLuint)
        oglLoadImg (Left e) = return $ Left e 
        oglLoadImg (Right png) = do
            ... I need todo IO stuff in here
```

The code above seems really bloated and nasty. What can I do to make it simpler?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You essentially want a combination of the `Either e` monad and the `IO` monad. That's what [monad transformers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) are for!

In this case, you can use [the `ErrorT` monad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Error.html) which adds error handling using `Either` to an underlying monad, in this case `IO`.

```
import Control.Monad.Error

loadTexture :: String -> IO (Either String GL.GLuint)
loadTexture filename = runErrorT $ ErrorT (PNG.loadPNGFile filename) >>= oglLoadImg
    where
        oglLoadImg :: PNG.PNGImage -> ErrorT String IO GL.GLuint
        oglLoadImg png = do
            -- [...]
```

This keeps the old interface, although it would probably be even nicer to use `ErrorT` for your function as well, and have the call to `runErrorT` in your `main` function.

```
loadTexture :: String -> ErrorT String IO GL.GLuint
loadTexture filename = ErrorT (PNG.loadPNGFile filename) >>= oglLoadImg
    where
        oglLoadImg :: PNG.PNGImage -> ErrorT String IO GL.GLuint
        oglLoadImg png = do
            -- [...]
```

Monad transformers can take some getting used to, but they are very useful.

Comment: Instead of `ErrorT (PNG.loadPNGFile filename)` is it possible to use `return (PNG.loadPNGFile filename)`?

Answer (score 12):

Before doing stylistic refactoring, let's take a step back and think about the semantics of what your code is doing here.

You've got an `IO` action that produces something of type `Either String PNG.PNGImage`, where the `Left` case is an error message. You think want to do something with the `Right` case when it exists, while leaving the error message as is. Think about what this composite operation might look like, if you condensed it into a single, generalized combinator:

```
doIOWithError :: IO (Either String a) -> (a -> IO b) -> IO (Either String b)
doIOWithError x f = do x' <- x
                       case x' of
                           Left err -> return (Left err)
                           Right y  -> f y
```

While that could be useful as is, you may already have noticed that its type signature looks suspiciously similar to `(>>=) :: (Monad m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. In fact, if we generalize one step further by allowing the function to produce errors as well, we have exactly the type of `(>>=)` where `m a` becomes `IO (Either String a)`. Unfortunately, you can't make that a `Monad` instance, because you can't just glue type constructors together directly.

What you can do is wrap it in a newtype alias, and in fact it turns out that someone already has: this is just `Either` used as a monad transformer, so we want `ErrorT String IO`. Rewriting your function to use that gives this:

```
loadTexture :: String -> ErrorT String IO GL.GLuint
loadTexture filename = do
    p <- ErrorT $ loadPNGFile filename
    lift $ oglLoadImg p
    where
        oglLoadImg :: PNG.PNGImage -> IO GL.GLuint
        oglLoadImg png = do putStrLn "...I need todo IO stuff in here"
                            return 0
```

Now that we've merged the conceptual composite operation, we can begin condensing the specific operations more effectively. Collapsing the `do` block into monadic function application is a good start:

```
loadTexture :: String -> ErrorT String IO GL.GLuint
loadTexture filename = lift . oglLoadImg =<< ErrorT (loadPNGFile filename)
    where
        oglLoadImg :: PNG.PNGImage -> IO GL.GLuint
        oglLoadImg png = do putStrLn "...I need todo IO stuff in here"
                            return 0
```

And depending on what you're doing in `oglLoadImg`, you might be able to do more.

Answer (score 4):

Use an instance of `Data.Traversable.Traversable` for `Either` and then `mapM`. An instance could be:

```
instance Traversable (Either a) where
  sequenceA (Left x)  = pure $ Left x
  sequenceA (Right x) = Right <$> x
```

Now you can simply use `forM`:

```
loadTexture :: String -> IO (Either String GL.GLuint)
loadTexture filename = do
  p <- PNG.loadPNGFile filename
  forM p $ \p -> do
    -- Whatever needs to be done
  -- continue here.
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
loadTexture :: String -> IO (Either String GL.GLuint)
loadTexture filename = either (return . Left) oglLoadImg =<< PNG.loadPNGFile filename
    where
        oglLoadImg :: PNG.PNGImage -> IO (Either String GL.GLuint)
        oglLoadImg png = do -- IO stuff in here
```

(I'm not totally happy with the `either (return . Left)` bit and wonder whether it can be replaced with some sort of `lift` incantation.)

Comment: Yes, `lift` is appropriate here. See the nearly-simultaneous answers by hammar and myself demonstrating `ErrorT` for details. :]

Comment: @tm1rbrt I ballsed up the type signature; hopefully fixed now. But hammer and C.A.McCann's answers are better.